# How to suppress duplicate validation error messages in custom MVC validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I've created person model with custom validation to insure the user enters a name for the person. The problem is the name is made up of several fields and i only require at least one of the fields be completed.

Here is my validation code:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.Title) && 
    string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.Initals) &&
    string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.Forename) && 
    string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.Surname) && 
    string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.Company))
    yield return new ValidationResult("You must enter a name or company name.", 
        new string[] { "Title", "Initals", "Forename", "Surname", "Company" });
```

I expected to see a single error message and 5 fields highlighted, however i get 5 error messages and five fields highlighted. I'm only displaying error messages using @Html.ValidationSummary().

How do I suppress the 4 extra messages and still highlight the 5 fields that are the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of quick solutions:

1) Set 2 ValidationResult in validation code:

```
...
yield return new ValidationResult("You must enter a name or company name.");
yield return new ValidationResult("any text",
    new string[] { "Title", "Initals", "Forename", "Surname", "Company" });
```

2) Exclude property validation message from summary, in your View:

```
@model SomeModel
...
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
...
```

So you'll get single message and highlighted inputs.